# Algorand ARC-19 and ARC-69. What exaclty is the difference?

Tags: nft, flowchart, algorand

I have been studying the Algorand ARC-19 and ARC-69 to see which one will better suit my use case. But I am finding it hard to understand them properly.

Can you help me better understand by providing sequence diagram for the data flow and operations that occur with creating an ASA in ARC-69?

Answer (score 1):

To give a bit of context:

- For a given ASA, the `URL field` is immutable
- The `Reserve Address` is mutable
  (If it has not been set to the *Zero Address* & the *Manager Address* exists)

By using a template, `template-ipfs://{ipfscid:1:raw:reserve:sha2-256}` [ARC-19](https://github.com/algorandfoundation/ARCs/blob/main/ARCs/arc-0019.md) allows client to read/display URL based on the value of the `Reserve Address`. (An IPFS hash can be obtained from the `Reserve Address`.)

[ARC-69](https://github.com/algorandfoundation/ARCs/blob/main/ARCs/arc-0069.md) is a community-based convention used for *Digital Media*.

- The `URL field` of the Asset points to a Media file (png, jpeg ...)
- The metadata associated with the Asset is stored inside the `Note Field`, which is accessible during the creation/config of the Asset. (If the `Manager Address` exist)
- Metadata Size is restricted (The `Note Field` can only contain [1024 Bytes](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/get-details/parameter_tables/#others))
- Metadata is stored **ON-CHAIN** and can be read only by querying an indexer (see [Archival Node](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/run-a-node/setup/types/#archival-mode))
- As long as the `Manager Address` is set, Metadata is mutable.

[ARC-3](https://github.com/algorandfoundation/ARCs/blob/main/ARCs/arc-0003.md) is a general Fungible/Non-Fungible Token convention.

- The `URL field` of the Asset points to an **OFF-CHAIN** IPFS file containing the Metadata (JSON based on [ERC-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155))
- This JSON file can have multiple fields and is not restricted in size.
- Metadata is stored **OFF-CHAIN**, so it can be read by querying the value inside the `URL Field` of the Asset from a non-Archival Node. (Which is way more convenient than using an Indexer)

To have mutability with **OFF-CHAIN** Data (which is encouraged & matches every case), ARC-19 can be combined with ARC-3.

1. The `Url Field` **MUST** be equal to `template-ipfs://{ipfscid:1:raw:reserve:sha2-256}#arc3`
2. `Reserve Address` **MUST** be set
3. `Manager Address` **MUST** be set

If you have more questions about ARC or Algorand in general, I encourage you to join the [Discord](https://discord.com/invite/algorand) and the [Forum](https://forum.algorand.org/).